# How to scroll to top of page when accordion is clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, accordion

I have the following jQuery, its working fine. What I need is when the accordion is clicked to take the user to the top of page of the active accordion.

Here is the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.accordion-container').hide();

    //$('.accordion-toggle:first').addClass('active').next().show();

    $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){
        if( $(this).next().not(':hidden') ) {
            $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();

        }
        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {

            $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();

            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();

        }

        return false; // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor

    });    
});
```

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use plain javascript to scroll the page programmatically:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

Here's what your code should look like:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    $('.accordion-container').hide();

    //$('.accordion-toggle:first').addClass('active').next().show();

    $('.accordion-toggle').click(function(){

        if( $(this).next().not(':hidden') ) {
            $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();

        }

        if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) {

            $('.accordion-toggle').removeClass('active').next().slideUp();

            $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown();

        }

        //scroll to top
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);

        return false; // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor

    });    

});
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, would you please let me know where exactly in the code do I add window.scrollTo(0, 0);

Comment: @user3019325 I added more code. I'm not 100% sure how you want to do it, so just play with it a bit and you'll figure it out in no time.

Comment: Thank you again, it worked but now its take me to the top of the whole page I only want it to take me to the top of the active accordion.

Comment: Then say so in your question. You specifically stated you wanted it to take the user "to the top of the page." Do a bit of searching and learn how to retrieve the Y coordinate of the top of the accordion and use it in `window.scrollTo(0, yCoordinate);`.

Comment: I did say that in the question. Anyways thank you for your time :)

Comment: Don't forget to select an answer once you've received one that works for you.

Comment: I'm still looking for an answer, but I will

Comment: I could not find another solution but I used your recommendation with a small adjustment and it did the trick window.scrollTo(0, 500); thank you very much

Comment: @user3019325 Glad to hear it. One thing that might help: search around on how to get the position of an element on the page, then use the Y coordinate instead of just the 500. You might get more accurate results.